# Gravity Forms Conditional Logic based on Save and Continue

Tags: jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Forms and would like to make some fields conditional upon return from the Save and Continue link.

My form is for users to enter their match details for a pool match and after I gather the other player's name (I already have theirs) I calculate the player targets based on their handicaps and display them. I ask them to click on Save and Continue because the match could take a couple hours.

When they click on the link to return to the form, I want to display the remaining fields for reporting their scores.

I contacted Gravity Forms tech support and they suggested I could create some custom script that checks if there is a gf_token parameter in the URL and then fills some field that can trigger your conditional logic.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this but thought maybe someone here could shortcut my journey.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same question, and I don't know if you ever found a solution, so I am going to post what I found.

If you view the source code of the rendered form, the conditionals have an onClick="" function on them.  Something like:

**gf_apply_rules(2,[30,25,26,27,28,29]);**

The 2 refers to the form ID and the array of numbers refer to the fields it is going to effect.  I found that you don't really need this.  You just need the form id.

**gf_apply_rules(2);**

This is what triggers the conditionals once values change.  At the bottom of the page below the form (not in the gravity form, but in the footer of the page), I did a:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    gf_apply_rules(2);
});
</script>
```

You have to change the 2 to the form ID that you are including.  And make sure you have a jquery library loaded in order for it to understand the ready() function.  If you don't have direct access to the source files or template files, there are plugins within wordpress that will let you modify the footer information.

Lastly, I also had to include the jQuery file in the header:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Still expecting a "t" parameter (The function expects 3 parameters: gf_apply_rules(e, t, i) ).